# What is the right way to render PDF with correct orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, pdf-generation, core-graphics

I am rendering PDFs using core graphics, **CGContextDrawPDFPage** function. I am trying to show the PDF pages in image views. The pages are getting rendered perfectly. But some pages are not in correct orientation. Some are flipped right, upside-down. This happens for only a few PDFs/pages, not for all. The following the code snippet that renders the PDF pages. I've seen a lot of posts online, but all of them are failing in some way. Also I am not much familiar with the core graphics.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = NULL;
CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bmi = (kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, target_w, target_h, 8, 0, rgb, bmi);

if (context != NULL) {

    CGRect thumbRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, target_w, target_h);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    CGContextFillRect(context, thumbRect);
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    CGRect mediaRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(thePDFPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, target_w / mediaRect.size.width, target_h / mediaRect.size.height);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -mediaRect.origin.x, -mediaRect.origin.y);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, thePDFPageRef);
    imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
}

CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);

if (imageRef != NULL) {

     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:UIScreen.mainScreen.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
     CFRelease(imageRef);
 }
```

Please suggest me the perfect way to render PDFs.

Comment: Could anyone please shed some light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this help you, because I'm not entirely sure, what are you trying to capture in your pdf.

However, when I did it, I needed to do pdf from my webview. For this, you need to

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and then

```
        CGRect frame = myWebView.frame;
        frame.size.height = 1;
        myWebView.frame = frame;
        CGSize fittingSize = [myWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
        frame.size = fittingSize;
        myWebView.frame = frame;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fittingSize, YES, 2);
        [myWebView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        UIImageView *myImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:viewImage];
        NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, myImg.bounds, nil);
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

        [myImg.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```